# How to modify the abb_driver support package so that ROS can be used to control the coordinated movement of dual robotic arms

Tags: ros, communication, abb

First of all, please note: The RobotWare version is 6.15, and the dual robotic arms have only one controller (with MultiMove control module), and the ROS version is noetic.

My question is how to establish communication between ROS and dual robot arms. What is certain is that if there is only one robotic arm, then I can easily establish communication through the abb_driver support package, and then control the movement of the real robotic arm through ROS.

I checked some information, and some people said that when controlling dual robot arms, the six configuration files of the rapid part in abb_driver need to be modified (or increased to 12). I think what he said is right, but it is not a sufficient condition and there are still some steps missing.

To summarize, I don't know how to modify the rapid part of the code. Do I need some other work so that I can establish complete communication between ROS and abb dual robotic arms?

Thanks！

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!  [ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver) package may help. Please go through the documentation and try it.

Comment: Yes, I have paid attention to the abb_robot_driver package, but there is no EGM interface on my dual robot arms. And I found that one difference between the abb_driver and abb_robot_driver packages is that the rapid code file is not provided in abb_robot_driver. Does this mean that the existence of the EGM interface does not require me to do any configuration in robotware, and only needs to be configured in ROS for communication?